# Class field resets to zero

Tags: c++, oop

im trying to make a simple game engine, it consists of 2 classes, Game

```
class Game
{
    protected:
        SDL_Event event;
        vector<Sprite> render_queue;

        void render();

    public:
        int SCREEN_WIDTH,
            SCREEN_HEIGHT,
            SCREEN_BPP,
            FPS;
        SDL_Surface *screen;

        Game(int width, int height, int fps);
        void reset_screen();
        void set_caption(string caption);
        bool update();
        void quit();
        void add_sprite(Sprite spt);
};
```

and Sprite

```
class Sprite
{
    public:
        float x,y;
        SDL_Surface* graphics;

        Sprite();
        void draw(SDL_Surface *target);
        void loadGraphics(string path);
};
```

when im trying to change x or y of sprite it resets to 0 on next frame!

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    Game testing(640, 480, 50);
    testing.set_caption("Test");

    Sprite s1;
    Sprite s2;

    s1.loadGraphics("img1.png");
    s2.loadGraphics("img1.jpg");

    testing.add_sprite(s1);
    testing.add_sprite(s2);

    while(!testing.update())
    {
        s1.x = 100;
        s2.y = 200;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hard to help here without the update() and add_sprite() code, as well as whatever else they might call.

Answer (score 3):

You make copies of the sprites when adding them to the `Game`:

```
class Game
{
        /* ... */
        void add_sprite(Sprite spt);
};
```

That's why the lines `s1.x = 100;` and `s2.y = 200;` (operating on a different copy in the `main()`) have no effect.

I think the method should be instead defined like that:

```
class Game
{
        /* ... */
        void add_sprite(Sprite &spt);
};
```

That way `Game` would be using the `Sprite` objects from the `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

testing.add_sprite(s2); makes a copy of sprite, so changing the value of s1,s2 in the main code has no effect on the copy in testing.

You need to pass by reference or pointer to to add_sprite()